# App published in google play with JDK 1.7

Tags: android, google-play

We published our android app into google play with JDK 1.7.
When the app got published the users were able to download but NOT install .

Found the solution for this.It ws to downgrade jdk to 1.6.
I took another build of the app and tried testing with the previous keystore, but it threw an error.

So i created a new keystore with jdk 1.6 and tried pushing it into google play , i get this new error "keystore mismatch.App cannot have a new key store"

I also found that i cannot use a different keystore.
but my previous keystore doesnt allow itself to be installed.What do i do now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to publish a new app, with different package name because Google play will not let you update an app with a different key store, nor will they let you publish a new app with the same package name.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try exporting the keys from the JDK 1.7 keystore and importing them into the 1.6 keystore. You may be able to use your old signing key that way.

If not, then you're stuck. As far as the app at Google Play is concerned, you cannot change signing key once the app has been published. However, you can withdraw the app from publication and publish a different app with the same title. It will need to have a different package name and Google Play will consider it to be a completely different app.

Comment: Hi ted,I have downgraded the jdk from 1.7 to 1.6.Now how i can i re export the key using jdk1.6

Comment: As a quick solution i published another app under a diff bundle id ,but same name.

Comment: @elixirbash - You can use the keytool app that is packaged with JDK 1.7 to export the key, then the keytool that comes with JDK 1.6 to import it into a 1.6 keystore.